# Redis losing connection in docker container

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I am making a PubSub using redigo and the connection is created by redis pool.

This is the Redis Pool code:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
)

type IRedis interface {
    Addr() string
    Conn() redis.Conn
    Set(key string, body string) error
    Close()
}

type Redis struct {
    addr string
    pool *redis.Pool
}

func NewRedis(addr string) *Redis {
    r := &Redis{
        addr,
        &redis.Pool{
            MaxIdle:     50000,
            IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
            Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
                c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", addr)
                if err != nil {
                    return nil, err
                }
                return c, err
            },
            TestOnBorrow: func(c redis.Conn, t time.Time) error {
                _, err := c.Do("PING")
                return err
            },
        },
    }

    r.cleanupHook()
    return r
}

func (r *Redis) cleanupHook() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGTERM)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGKILL)
    go func() {
        <-c
        r.pool.Close()
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
}

func (r *Redis) Addr() string {
    return r.addr
}

func (r *Redis) Conn() redis.Conn {
    return r.pool.Get()
}

func (r *Redis) Set(key string, body string) error {
    p := r.pool.Get()
    defer p.Close()

    _, err := p.Do("SET", key, body)
    return err
}

func (r *Redis) Close() {
    r.pool.Close()
}
```

This is my PubSub code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
)

type PubSub struct {
    send chan string
    conn *redis.PubSubConn
}

func NewPubSub(s chan string, c *redis.PubSubConn) (*PubSub, error) {
    err := c.Subscribe("urls")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &PubSub{s, c}, nil
}

func (ps *PubSub) Start() {
    for {
        switch v := ps.conn.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
            data := string(v.Data)
            ps.send <- data

        case redis.Subscription:
            log.Printf("subscription message: %s: %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)

        case error:
            log.Println("error:", v)
            return
        }
    }
}

func (ps *PubSub) Close() {
    ps.conn.Close()
}
```

and after I receive 10k messages in my PubSub channel the connection is lost and I receive an redis.Error with the message EOF

Any thoughts why this is happen?
Even when I run locally the problem happens

Comment: the log shows nothing and if I run the application locally it works as a charm. Any thoughts why doesn't work with docker? the redis image is redis:alpine

Comment: @ThunderCat see comment above

Comment: @ThunderCat it is a redis.Error with message EOF and both are running in docker. Also, I've tested running just redis in docker and client locally but throws same error.

Comment: @ThunderCat yes, you understood right. I mean that redis sends redis.error with message EOF and I lost the connection with it. Like the current connection is closed and I cannot receive message anymore.
The program doesn't panic

Comment: It would really be helpful if you'd include the full code to reproduce (and also spam the internet less - no need to open issues all over the place). That said, why are you doing `ps.conn.Receive()` when the docs clearly state `ps.Receive()`?

Comment: @ItamarHaber I've created a PubSub abstraction and conn holds the connection to redis. That's why the `ps.conn.Receive()`

Comment: @ThunderCat FYI the problem happens in local as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with parameter in redis conf called client-output-buffer-limit pubsub which the default value is 32mb 8mb 60 and when the limit is reached redis closes the connection with the pubsub.
To solve it I've increased the value.

Comment: It's absolutely fine to mark own answers as such, you know ;)